# What is a standards-based protocol?

Tags: rip

> Routing Information Protocol (RIP) is a standards-based, distance-vector, interior gateway protocol (IGP) used by routers to exchange routing information.

What does it mean by standards-based protocol?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

It's an open standard and not vendor proprietary.  EIGRP is an example of a Cisco proprietary routing protocol, and OSPF is an example of a standards-based routing protocol.

Using standards-based protocols makes transitions between hardware vendors easier, although proprietary protocols sometimes have benefits you may want to use.

Comment: Open vs. Closed doesn't change anything; they can both be "standards". A "standard" means there's a defining document for the thing. In this case (w.r.t. RIP), "standards-based" refers to the IETF "internet standards" process. (i.e. there's an RFC defining it.)

Answer (score 0):

Open standards encourage interoperability, competition, and innovation. They also guarantee that no single company’s product can monopolize the market, or have an unfair advantage over its competition.

A good example of this is when purchasing a wireless router for the home. There are many different choices available from a variety of vendors, all of which incorporate standard protocols such as IPv4, DHCP, 802.3 (Ethernet), and 802.11 (Wireless LAN). These open standards also allow a client running Apple’s OS X operating system to download a web page from a web server running the Linux operating system. This is because both operating systems implement the open standard protocols, such as those in the TCP/IP protocol suite.